# How to convert a complex conjugate column matrix to row matrix?

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix as follow with dimension nx1:

```
A=[1+3i
1-5i
 1+2i
....]
```

I want to calculate its conjugative (A*) and still remain nx1, How to do it? I do by using A', but after the dimension is 1xn.
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You first need the [**complex conjugate transpose**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html) `A'` and then you can simply [**transpose**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html) `A.'` it back:

```
A = (A').'
```

but what you actually want is:

```
A = conj(A)
```

which is only the [**complex conjugate**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conj.html) **without** transposing.